# shutdown when upgraded ubuntu from 11.10 to 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade

I shutdown my system when it was upgrading. Now I can only login in low graphics mode (only have a terminal) and cannot connect to the Internet. How do I fix it?

Comment: What have you tried?  What internet connections do you have available to you (wireless/wired)?

Answer (score 0):

You should first try to get the internet working again from the command line. It's hard to help without knowing what kind of internet connection you are using. Perhaps you can improve your question?

Assuming internet works, you can run:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This should restart the failed upgrade process and will hopefully repair whatever is causing the graphical login to fail.

If it doesn't you could try the following, but you might want to take a backup first:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

If you can't get the internet working, download the latest ubuntu iso image. Put it on a CD or USB and make it visible to the apt packaging system. See this question on askubuntu for some pointers:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/4694/how-to-use-a-iso-image-as-a-cd-rom-repository